# Deve-se evitar usar vírgula entre orações subordinadas substantivas e a oração principal?

Tags: sintaxe, pontuação, orações-subordinadas, vírgula

A recomendação que não se deve usar vírgula entre orações subordinadas substantivas e a oração principal está correta?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

De  [esta fonte](http://www.portuguesfacil.net/regras-simples-faceis-usar-virgula/):

> #### Use a vírgula para separar elementos que você poderia listar:
>
> > João Maria Ricardo Pedro e Augusto foram almoçar.
>
> Note que os nomes das pessoas poderiam ser separados em uma lista:
>
> Foram almoçar:
>
> - João
> - Maria
> - Ricardo
> - Pedro
> - Augusto
>
> Isso significa que devem ser separados por vírgula na frase original:
>
> > João, Maria, Ricardo, Pedro e Augusto foram almoçar.
>
> Note que antes de “e Augusto” não vai vírgula. Como regra geral, não
>   se usa vírgula antes de “e”. Há um caso específico que eu explico
>   daqui a pouco. Um outro exemplo:
>
> > A sua fronte, a sua boca, o seu riso, as suas lágrimas, enchem-lhe a voz de formas e de cores… (Teixeira de Pascoaes)
>
> #### Use a vírgula para separar explicações que estão no meio da frase
>
> Explicações que interrompem a frase são mudanças de pensamento e devem
>   ser separadas por vírgula. Exemplos:
>
> > Mário, **o moço que traz o pão**, não veio hoje.
>
> Dá-se uma explicação sobre quem é Mário. Se tivéssemos que classificar
>   sintaticamente o trecho, seria um aposto.
>
> > Eu e você, **que somos amigos**, não devemos brigar.
>
> O trecho destacado explica algo sobre “Eu e você”, portanto deve vir
>   entre vírgulas. A classificação do trecho seria oração adjetiva
>   explicativa.
>
> #### Use a vírgula para separar o lugar, o tempo ou o modo que vier no início da frase.
>
> Quando um tipo específico de expressão — aquela que indica tempo,
>   lugar, modo e outros — iniciar a frase, usa-se vírgula. Em outras
>   palavras, separa-se o adjunto adverbial antecipado. Exemplos:
>
> > **Lá fora**, o sol está de rachar!
>
> “Lá fora” é uma expressão que indica “lugar”. Um adjunto adverbial de
>   lugar.
>
> > **Semana passada**, todos vieram jantar aqui em casa.
>
> “Semana passada” indica tempo. Adjunto adverbial de tempo.
>
> > **De um modo geral**, não gostamos de pessoas estranhas.
>
> “De um modo geral” é sinônimo de “geralmente”, adjunto adverbial de
>   modo, por isso vai vírgula.
>
> #### Use a vírgula para separar orações independentes
>
> Orações independentes são aquelas que têm sentido, mesmo estando fora
>   do texto. Nós já vimos um tipo dessas, que são as orações coordenadas
>   assindéticas, mas também há outros casos. Vamos ver os exemplos:
>
> > Acendeu um cigarro, cruzou as pernas, estalou as unhas, demorou o olhar em Mana Maria. (A. de Alcântara Machado)
>
> Nesse exemplo, cada vírgula separa uma oração independente. Elas são
>   coordenadas assindéticas.
>
> > Eu gosto muito de chocolate, **mas** não posso comer para não engordar.
> >
> > Eu gosto muito de chocolate, **porém** não posso comer para não engordar.
> >
> > Eu gosto muito de chocolate, **contudo** não posso comer para não engordar.
> >
> > Eu gosto muito de chocolate, **no entanto** não posso comer para não engordar.
> >
> > Eu gosto muito de chocolate, **entretanto** não posso comer para não engordar.
> >
> > Eu gosto muito de chocolate, **todavia** não posso comer para não engordar.
>
> Antes de todas essas palavras aí, chamadas de conjunções adversativas,
>   vai vírgula. Pra quem gosta de saber os nomes (se é que tem alguém),
>   elas se chamam orações coordenadas sindéticas adversativas.
>
> #### Quando se usa vírgula antes de “e”?
>
> Vimos aí em cima que, como regra geral, não se usa vírgula antes de
>   “e”. Tem só um caso em que vai vírgula, que é quando a frase depois do
>   “e” fala de uma pessoa, coisa, ou objeto (sujeito) diferente da que
>   vem antes dele. Assim:
>
> > O sol já ia fraco, e a tarde era amena. (Graça Aranha)
>
> Note que a primeira frase fala do sol, enquanto a segunda fala da
>   tarde. Os sujeitos são diferentes. Portanto, usamos vírgula. Outro
>   exemplo:
>
> > A mulher morreu, e cada um dos filhos procurou o seu destino (F. Namora)
>
> Mesmo caso, a primeira oração diz respeito à mulher, a segunda aos
>   filhos.
>
> #### Existem casos em que a vírgula é opcional?
>
> Existe um caso. Lembra do item 3, aí em cima? Se a expressão de tempo,
>   modo, lugar etc. não for uma expressão, mas sim uma palavra só, então
>   a vírgula é facultativa. Vai depender do sentido, do ritmo, da
>   velocidade que você quer dar para a frase. Exemplos:
>
> > Depois vamos sair para jantar. Depois, vamos sair para jantar.
> >
> > Geralmente gosto de almoçar no shopping. Geralmente, gosto de almoçar no shopping.
> >
> > Semana passada, todos vieram jantar aqui em casa. Semana passada todos vieram jantar aqui em casa.
>
> Note que esse último é o mesmo exemplo do item 3. Vê como sem a
>   vírgula a frase também fica correta? Mesmo não sendo apenas uma
>   palavra, dificilmente algum professor dará errado se você omitir a
>   vírgula.
>
> #### Não se usa a vírgula!
>
> Com as regras acima, pode ter certeza de que você vai acertar 99% dos
>   casos em que precisará da vírgula. Um erro muito comum que vejo é
>   gente separando sujeito e predicado com vírgula. Isso é errado, e você
>   pode ser preso se for pego usando!
>
> Jeito errado:
>
> > João, gosta de comer batatas.
> >
> > Alice, Maria e Luíza, querem ir para a escola amanhã.
>
> Jeito certo:
>
> > João gosta de comer batatas.
> >
> > Alice, Maria e Luíza querem ir para a escola amanhã.

Comment: @JorgeB. Mas isto é uma reprodução, palavra por palavra, da fonte; e não diz nada sobre orações subordinadas substantivas, que é o objeto da pergunta.

Comment: Excellent copy-and-paste job...

Answer (score 8):

**RESPOSTA CURTA**

Não se separam **orações subordinadas substantivas** (a partir de agora, **OSS**) da **oração principal** (a partir de agora, **OP**), com uma exceção. Vamos deixa a exceção para o fim e começar pelos cinco tipos de OSS em que não há vírgula; nos exemplos seguintes, a OP está em letra normal e a OSS, em negrito itálico:

> **(a) Objetiva direta:** Quero ***que você me aqueça nesse inverno***.
>
> **(b) Objetiva indireta:** Certifiquei-me ***de que todos os convidados já chegaram***.
>
> **(c) Subjetiva:** É imprescindível ***que ele pare de fumar***.
>
> **(d) Completiva nominal:** Tenho confiança ***em que ele cumpra o que prometeu***.
>
> **(e) Predicativa:** O nosso receio era ***que não conseguíssemos chegar a tempo.***

Como se pode ver, uma vírgula entre a oração principal e a OSS não faria sentido. Explicam Celso Cunha e Lindley Cintra na *Nova Gramática do Português Contemporâneo* (Lisboa, 1984, p. 806; a secção inteira da gramática está reproduzida na [Gramática Aulete online](http://www.aulete.com.br/gram/cap19-01-sinais_que_marcam_sobretudo_a_pausa)) que a vírgula marca uma pausa breve na fala, e qualquer dos exemplos acima lê-se sem pausa entre a oração principal e a OSS. Isto fica mais evidente se compararmos com um frase em que há pausas:

> O meu tio João, que é o meu tio favorito, também vem à festa.

Neste exemplo a oração principal é “o meu tio João também vem à festa,” e intercalada no meio dela está a oração subordinada adjetiva explicativa “que é o meu tio favorito.” As duas vírgulas correspondem a pausas breves na fala; pausas que não existem nos exemplos (a) a (e).

**RESPOSTA LONGA**

Vejamos a sintaxe de cada tipo de **oração subordinada substantiva.**

**(a) OSS objetiva direta.** Vê-se que a oração principal é simplesmente “quero,” e a OSS é o seu objeto direto. Seria como dizer “quero ***algo.***” Em (a) o *algo* é “que você me aqueça nesse inverno.” Em qualquer dos casos, não se separa com vírgula o verbo do seu objeto direto. É claro que podemos intercalar outra oração entre a OSS e a principal. Por exemplo: “quero, apesar de tudo o que você me fez, que você me aqueça nesse inverno,” mas não é isto que está em causa.

> (a) Quero ***que você me aqueça nesse inverno*** (Quero algo.)
> Eles não reconhecem ***que se enganaram.*** (Não reconhecem algo.)
> A Joana verificou ***se todos os convidados já tinham chegado.*** (Verificou algo.)

**(b) OSS objetiva indireta.** Aqui a OSS exerce a função de objeto indireto do verbo da oração principal. Em (b) seria como dizer “certifiquei-me de ***algo***, em que o *algo* neste caso é “que todos os convidados já chegaram.” Novamente, não se separa com vírgula o verbo do seu objeto indireto. O objeto indireto requer uma preposição, *de*, neste exemplo. Contudo nas construções com OSS objetivas indiretas omite-se por vezes a preposição:

> (b) Certifiquei-me ***(de) que todos os convidados já chegaram.*** (Certifiquei-me de algo.)
> Eles insistiram ***(em) que eu jantasse com eles.*** (Insistiram em algo.)

**(c) OSS subjetiva**. Esta é para mim uma das mais curiosas: a OSS exerce a função de sujeito do verbo da oração principal. Em (c) seria como dizer “***algo*** é imprescindível” em que o *algo* é “que ele deixe de fumar.” A OSS fica melhor depois da oração principal, mas nada nos impediria de dizer “que ele pare de fumar é imprescindível.” Novamente, sujeito e verbo não podem ser separados por vírgula.

> (c) É imprescindível ***que ele pare de fumar***. (Algo é imprescindível.)
> É óbvio ***que ela não quer nada contigo***. (Algo é óbvio.)

**(d) OSS completiva nominal.** Em (d), a OSS complementa um nome, “confiança,” da oração principal. Seria como dizer “tenho confiança em ***algo***.” Novamente, a preposição de ligação do nome ao seu complemento pode por vezes ser omitida na construção com OSS. (d2) é um exemplo de OSS reduzida, em que ***que*** + verbo conjugado é substituído pelo verbo no infinitivo.

> (d) Tenho confiança (em) ***que ele cumpra o que prometeu***. (Confiança em algo.)
> (d1) Temos autorização ***para que avancemos com o projeto.*** (Temos autorização para algo.)
> (d2) Temos autorização ***para avançar com o projeto***. (Temos autorização para algo.)

**(e) OSS predicativa.** Aqui a OSS é um predicativo do sujeito do verbo da oração principal. Em (e), seria como dizer “o nosso receio era ***algo***”, em que *algo*, o predicativo de “nosso receio”, é “que não conseguíssemos chegar a tempo.” Novamente, não se separa com vírgula o verbo do predicativo do sujeito.

> (e) O nosso receio era ***que não conseguíssemos chegar a tempo.*** (O receio é algo.)
> (e1, OSS reduzida.) O nosso receio era ***não conseguirmos chegar a tempo.*** (O receio é algo.)
> A sua única exigência é ***que não façamos nada sem o avisar primeiro.*** (A exigência é algo.)

Resta-nos um tipo de OSS: a OSS apositiva. Neste caso a OSS é um [aposto](http://www.aulete.com.br/aposto) dum nome da oração principal. Um exemplo de aposto é “o meu tio favorito” em “o meu tio João, o meu tio favorito, também vem à festa.” Neste caso o aposto dá uma explicação acerca de um nome da oração, “o meu tio João” neste caso. Os apostos vêm sempre separados por vírgula, parênteses ou travessão do nome que qualificam. Isto não muda quando o aposto é uma OSS, embora neste caso dois pontos seja mais natural. Na verdade este parágrafo começa com uma construção com OSS apositiva. Repito-a aqui com mais um exemplo:

> Resta-nos um tipo de OSS: ***a OSS apositiva***.
> Só quero uma coisa: ***que você me aqueça nesse inverno***.

Portanto é por isto que, com exceção da OSS apositiva, não se pode separar a OSS da oração principal por vírgula. Citando Celso Cunha e Lindley Cintra (p. 814; tambén na [Gramatica Aulete online](http://www.aulete.com.br/gram/cap19-01-sinais_que_marcam_sobretudo_a_pausa)):

> Os termos essenciais e integrantes da oração ligam-se uns com os outros sem pausa; não podem, assim, ser separados por vírgula. Esta a razão por que não é admissível o uso da vírgula entre uma oração subordinada substantiva e a sua principal.

Podem encontrar mais esclarecimentos e exemplos no [Só Escola](http://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/sint/sint30.php).

Comment: Bom trabalho Jacinto!

Answer (score 6):

Há um termo em Inglês "The Oxford Comma" que se refere à utilização de uma vírgula antes do último "e" numa lista. Isso pode fazer a diferença para o significado de uma frase.

Por exemplo:

> Eu gosto de comer queijo, chocolate, pão e geléia - todos eles são adoráveis.

ou

> Eu gosto de comer queijo, chocolate, pão, e geléia - todos eles são adoráveis.

Na primeira frase "pão" e "geléia" estariam ligados em conjunto como um único item, enquanto na segunda seriam tratados como itens separados.

[Espero que o meu Português esteja correto.]

Comment: Uma terceira forma de escrever essa frase poderia ser `Eu gosto de comer queijo, chocolate, e pão e geléia - todos eles são adoráveis.`.

Comment: (Já agora, no caso concreto de "pão com geleia" usamos "com" em vez de "e". Seria melhor procurar outro exemplo.)