# Dúvida sobre análise sintática de: a verdade é que você mentiu para o fiscal

Tags: sintaxe, orações-subordinadas

No exemplo a seguir:

> A verdade é que você mentiu para o fiscal.

A oração pode ser classificada como subordinada substantiva predicativa?

Porquê?

Comment: Não terias como editar o título da questão, para que não fique tão genérico?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode e deve. A frase é composta de duas orações:

> (a) Oração principal: *a verdade é*
>
> (b) Oração subordinada substantiva predicativa: *que você mentiu para o fiscal*.

(b) diz-se predicativa porque constitui o [***predicativo***](http://www.aulete.com.br/predicativo) do sujeito da oração principal (*verdade*). Ou seja, é um atributo ou a identidade do sujeito. Neste caso é a identidade: diz o que é que a verdade é. Diz-se substantiva porque desempenha um papel habitualmente desempenhado por substantivos. É como dizer "a verdade é *algo*, em que neste caso o *algo* é "que você mentiu para o fiscal."

Outros exemplos, com a oração principal em romano e a subordinada substantiva predicativa em negrito itálico:

> (c) O nosso desejo é ***que vocês cheguem em segurança***.
>
> (d) O nosso objetivo é ***vencer o jogo***.

(d) é um exemplo de oração reduzida: equivalente a *o nosso objetivo é que vençamos o jogo*, mas mais elegante. Nestes dois exemplos é mais fácil ver a razão de se do nome *substantiva*. Estas orações subordinadas substantivas poderiam ser substituídas por uma expressão com um substantivo por núcleo: "o nosso desejo é a vossa *chegada* em segurança" e "o nosso objetivo é a *vitória* no jogo".

Para mais informação e contrastação com outros tipos de orações subordinadas substantivas, têm aqui [esta resposta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/16/deve-se-evitar-usar-v%C3%ADrgula-entre-ora%C3%A7%C3%B5es-subordinadas-substantivas-e-a-ora%C3%A7%C3%A3o-p/1429#1429) e o [só português](http://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/sint/sint34.php).