# Sintaxe na oração

Tags: verbos, transitividade-verbal

Na frase abaixo há dois verbos. Nas repostas que tenho aqui só existe transitividade para o verbo confiar que é VTI. Com relação ao verbo afirmar, qual a sua transitividade?

> Durante a audiência,o réu afirmou não confiar no seu advogado.

Comment: O verbo afirmar, nesse contexto, é V.T.D. (Quem afirma, afirma algo [a alguém]). Como não há o objeto indireto, podemos concluir que é um V.T.D. O réu está garantindo a veracidade de algo.

Comment: No caso , (afirmou) é VTD seu objeto direto é " não confiar no seu advogado." ? e como fica o verbo confiar? é VTI e também faz parte do objeto direto de (afirmou)?

Comment: @thiago, sim, *confiar* é nessa frase transitivo indireto, porque se liga ao seu objeto por preposição, *confiar **em*** -- *confiou **n**o*... Outra coisa, tu não és o Thiago Xavier das outras perguntas? Se és, devias ter criado mais esta conta; devias fazer as perguntas todas a partir da mesma conta.

Comment: obrigado.Não sou ele.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nessa frase, o verbo *afirmar* é transitivo direto: o réu afirmou algo. Só que esse “algo” está expresso não por um substantivo, mas sim por uma oração subordinada: “algo” = “não confiar no seu advogado”. Repara como o seguinte diálogo soa tão natural, e na segunda frase já é óbvio que *afirmar* é transitivo direto:

> Ana: Durante a audiência, o réu afirmou **não confiar no seu advogado**.
>
> Bruno: Sério?! O réu afirmou **isso**?!

Na frase original o objeto direto de *afirmar*—“não confiar no seu advogado”—é uma oração subordinada reduzida de infinitivo, porque o verbo está no infinitivo. Poderíamos dizer a mesma coisa com uma oração subordinada desenvolvida (com o verbo numa forma finita):

> Durante a audiência, o réu afirmou **que não confiava no seu advogado**.

É comum o objeto direto de um verbo transitivo ser expresso por uma oração subordinada, reduzida ou desenvolvida. Então com verbos que exprimem comunicação, isto é especialmente comum:

> O réu disse **que era inocente**. (Disse algo.)
> O réu disse **ser inocente**. (Disse algo.)
>
> O réu negou **que tivesse visitado a vítima.** (Negou algo.)
> O réu negou **ter visitado a vítima.**
>
> O réu perguntou **se podia mudar de advogado**. (Perguntou algo.)

Com *perguntar*, não me parece possível a oração reduzida. Estas orações subordinadas dizem-se *substantivas* (porque exprimem algo tipicamente expresso por um substantivo) ou completivas, e podem desempenhar o papel de complemento direto do verbo, complemento indireto, sujeito, etc. Podes ver esta [resposta sobre estas orações](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/16/deve-se-evitar-usar-v%C3%ADrgula-entre-ora%C3%A7%C3%B5es-subordinadas-substantivas-e-a-ora%C3%A7%C3%A3o-p/1429#1429) ou esta página do [Só Português](https://portugues.uol.com.br/gramatica/oracoes-subordinadas-desenvolvidas-reduzidas.html), que abre a exposição precisamente com o verbo *afirmar*—“a garota afirmou precisar/que precisava de ajuda”.